# Write access denied when mounting folder from qemu guest

Tags: kvm, qemu, libvirt

I have setup a qemu Linux guest using virt-manager. I have mounted a host path successfully. The libvirt configuration snippet on the host:

```
<filesystem type='mount' accessmode='mapped'>
  <source dir='/home/robert/Documents/sources/oss/linux'/>
  <target dir='/linux-src'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0'/>
</filesystem>
```

The fstab line on the guest:

```
/linux-src /mnt/linux-src 9p defaults 0 0
```

Accessing and reading works fine, but I'm unable to write to that directory

```
$ cd /mnt/linux-src
$ touch asd
$ touch: cannot touch 'asd': Permission denied
```

I am running as the `root` user in the guest and the files belong to my user (`robert`) on the host.

What can I do to allow write access to that folder from the guest?

Comment: have you tried accessmode `passthrough` ?

Comment: @mazs - using `accessmode='passthrough'` brings the same result

Answer (score 4):

Give the `libvirt-qemu` group write access on the host:

```
chgrp libvirt-qemu /home/robert/Documents/sources/oss/linux
chmod -R g+w /home/robert/Documents/sources/oss/linux
```

Comment: This kinda works, but (at least for me) the files created from within the guest are now owned by group *and* *user* libvirt-qemu in the host, instead of user robert.